# How to open a port in Kubuntu

Tags: port, postgresql-9.4

i am trying to set up a postgres server but i dont understand what should i do to allow connections from remote pc through port 5432(i have already set up the 2 .conf files).Could anyone explain me how to open that port?

Answer (score 1):

you are not obliged to allow remote access to your server. but if you want to do it , you can read to know how to do it  http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/postgres-allow-remote-access-tcp-connection.html

Comment: thank you! i need to allow remote access because i am devoloping a mobile application and i need a server to test it.Can you confirm that i can use postgres to do that??

Comment: can you give more details about your context ?

Comment: Sure! I am developing a mobile application for an homework who is required to create a record with some informations involved every time the user declares he is having headache.All those records must be stored in a postgres database which is set in my pc.I communicate with the server via jdbc but the problem is that i can only communicate with my server if i use jdbc with locale connections.If i try to make a remote connections it fails reporting that the server is unable to connect and that the problems could be that the port is not open or the server do not accept remote connections

Comment: xx.xx.xx.xx is a public or local IP adresse ?
your mobile and PC are connected through ad-hoc, local network or internet ? 
did you check connection between them ?

Comment: i tried both with local ip and public but it report the same error. The mobile and the pc are both connected through internet.how can i check the connection between them?

Comment: I don't think that you'll be able  to connect them through internet.
I imagine that your local IP address is similar to 192.168.x.x for both devices ?

Answer (score 0):

Ok i solved it!! If anyone else have this problem,keep in mind that you need to create a virtual server within your router by operating with portforwarding